# adding line break in string data coming from database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.8

```
@forelse($orders as $order)
   <tr class="dropdown sliderow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{$order->id}}" data-parent="#myAccordion">
       <td >{{$order->id}}</td>
       <td>{{$order->customer_name}}</td>
       <td>{{$order->customer_email}}</td>
       <td>{{$order->customer_contact}}</td>
       <td>{{$order->customer_address}}</td>
       <td>
           <div class="action-box">
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-down">Details</i></a>
                {{--<a href=""><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>--}}
           </div>
       </td>
    <tr >
       <td colspan="6">
           <div class="container-fluid collapse" id="{{$order->id}}" style="position:relative;">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                       <h2>Customer info </h2>
                       <b>Name</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>{{$order->customer_name}}</span><br>
                       <b>Phone</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>{{$order->customer_contact}}</span><br>
                       <b>Address</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>{{$order->customer_address}}</span><br>

                       <h2>Products</h2>
                       <table cellpadding="1" class="table table-sm table-hover table-responsive">
                           <tr>
                               <th>name</th>
                               <th>quantity</th>
                               <th>total price</th>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td>{{$order->product_names}}</td>
                               <td>{{$order->products_quantity}}</td>
                               <td>PKR 70,000</td>
                            </tr>
                         </table>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <h4>order status</h4>

                          <select name="delivery_status" id="" class="form-control">
                               <option value="status" selected>status</option>
                               <option value="not-deliverd">shipped</option>
                               <option value="delivered">shipped and received by customer</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div></td></tr></tr>



          </div>
          @empty
             <tr class="text-center warning">
                 <td colspan="6">No Record Found</td>
             </tr>
          @endforelse
```

here the above code is my orders display code I want to add line breaks in product_name which is the string
and showing like Hp I7 8th generation, Huawei p30 pro
I want to break the line and add the second product which is after the comma in the next row of the table

*here is the image of how my products of the order are showing*
[image: here is the image of how my products of the order are showing]

Am I wrong in storing products in the database because I add customers product in the array and then convert it into the string for storing in database I now they are retrieving like this as shown in image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, storing `product_names` as a string goes against RDBMS principles; each product should be an entry in a separate table (`products`), linked to the order (`orders`) via some other method (generally a pivot table for `orders` and `products`, `orders_products`).

There is a simple way to display these, simply replace `,` in the string with `<br/>:`

```
<td>{!! str_replace("," "<br/>", $order->product_names) !!}</td>
```

Note: You have to use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}` so it outputs the HTML properly.

Answer (score 2):

first you have to add `<br/>` tag into your data.
find the length of your data and add `\n`at specific point.

```
       $length=strlen($order->product_names);
        if($length>50){
          $order->product_names = substr_replace($order->product_names," \n" , 
          position, 0);
        }
```

after that only just write your table cell just like below:

```
<td>{!! nl2br($order->product_names) !!}</td>
```

you have to just write `{!! !!}` rather then `{{ }}`